# Influence of measurement process on particle position

Tags: quantum-mechanics, measurements

The position of an electron sent "through" a double slit is indeterministic, but the probability of any possible position is determined by the particle's wave function. After much reading I have no idea, why nobody ever seems to have assumed that the outcome is deterministically determined by the measuring apparatus whose internal state on atomic level is of course unknown and never the same, when repeating the experiment, and could be responsible for the electron's measured final position, maybe according to some (far-too-complicated-for-humans) generalization of Schrodingers equation describing the behaviour of the measurement process as a whole. Why is this possiblity (which does NOT assume any hidden variable in the electron) never even been taken into consideration?

Comment: Are you sure it hasn't been taken into consideration? It sounds like superdeterminism: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superdeterminism

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for you answers. I found a simple answer myself (but it might be as wrong as the question itself): My question suggested, that when a wave with several maxima (e.g. a particle after diffraction) hits a detector screen, the Schrödinger equation for the system including the screen might enforce that one of these maxima survives and the other maxima vanish. But that's not plausible: When in a thought experiment two particles without diffraction and without entanglement are shot at the screen and hit the screen simultaneously at a distance of 1cm, no such effect (one maximum surviving, the other vanishing) is to be expected, and the Schrödinger equation does not "know" whether the wave approaching the screen is one particle or the superposition of two (or more) particles. So it seems very unlikely that maxima of a wave approaching some measurment apparatus vanish because of purely mathematical reasons.